# Ansible y máquinas virtuales

Tags: ubuntu

Buenoas, necesito hacer un playbook en Ansible tower que me permita crear una máquina virtual, a ser posible también montar WP en ella, pero no es prioritario que esté montado. Alguna idea de como hacer un playbook que cree una máquina virtual? soy bastante nuevo en ansible, estoy usando ubuntu debian

Comment: Nuevamente te sugiero revises [ask] para que modifiques tu pregunta y obtengas excelentes respuestas.

Comment: Primero tendrías que manejarte bien con Ansible (más que nada con los roles) y luego pasar a [Ansible Container](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-container/) que es la extensión que necesitas. Ansible Container se maneja muy parecido a Docker Compose. De hecho puedes ensayar haciendo tu máquina virtual con Docker y luego importando el dockerfile desde Ansible Container